# Unconnected sockets not implemented

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, axis

I have to access the webservice with 2 way authentication. Below is my approach.

Created MyCustomSSLSocketFactory class.

1. Loaded TrustManagers
2. Loaded Keystore Managers
3. Created SSL Context and SSL socket factory as below.

I call this class method just before calling webservice method.

Then i have done as below:-

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory",
                            "com.elipva.zephyr.twofa.util.MyCustomSSLSocketFactory");

Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider",
                    "com.elipva.zephyr.twofa.util.MyCustomSSLSocketFactory");


SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(protocolVersion);
context.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();

URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
  if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
    ((HttpsURLConnection) connection)
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

            connection.connect();
        }
```

when i access the webservice it gives me below error.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unconnected sockets not implemented
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:203)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: I have also tried the following way, but it dosent work.
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
Security.addProvider (new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,TLSv1");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "");ecurity.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

Comment: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "");
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

But the above approach gives me Handshake failure error. I am properly imported certificates and private key is there in pfx file which i am using in keystore settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be this Java bug - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6771432

Note that this is supposedly fixed in java 1.6.0_u14

Comment: Can you give some pointers as how can i work over 2 way SSL authentication, i have tried the above two approaches and seems only above two approaches are there available i forums also.

Comment: The problem got solved..for the second approach through system.properties ..just tried with the new keystores and truststores. we were using java 1.5 only. But my concern is how to use the first approach, can anybody help on that exception..unimplemented sockets...if somebody would have written a piece of code..pls share..it will be of gr8 use...

Comment: There are different webservice hosted, but when i access the services with "?wsdl" i get my wsdl file.

In  soap:address location value is something starting with "http" "http://XXXXXXX", 
but i need to change this from "http" to "HTTPS".

I tried changing axis2.xml and added transport receiver for https also, but it did not work.


Where i need to change, 
1.) service.xml..?? 
2.) or axis2.xml..??

Comment: Ran into the same exception supporting a legacy project running on java 1.4. Ultimately needed to uninstall the certificate from the cacerts file and then reinstall. After this the problem had resolved its self.

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved, simply imported certificates in cacerts file.

Comment: Can you please tell what kind of certificates you imported?